# How to combine pivot with cumulative sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a simple dataframe:

```
   type  | code | date    |value

0  apple | ap1  |08/12/14 |2
1  apple | ap1  |09/12/14 |12
2  apple | ap1  |10/12/14 |4
3  banana| b1   |08/12/14 |5
4  banana| b1   |09/12/14 |67
5  banana| b1   |10/12/14 |77
6  orange| o1   |08/12/14 |21
7  orange| o1   |09/12/14 |1
8  orange| o1   |10/12/14 |16
```

Which i can easily pivot with the dates as columns using the following function:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data,values=('value'),rows=['code','type'],cols='date',aggfunc=np.sum)
```

However I cant find a way to use a cumulative sum in place of the np.sum, I would like to display the data in the following format? Is this possible?

```
type    08/12/14    09/12/14    10/12/14
apple   2           12          4
banana  7           79          81
orange  28          80          97
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pandas is great, with a little help from a friend this is done by simply adding the following line:

```
pivot=pivot.cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks! Note: This will do a cumulative sum on the row. For cumulative sum across columns use `pivoted_dataframe.cumsum(axis=1)`